# Clean up mesh generated from overlapping curves

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

Suppose I have draw overlapping curves in order to simulate branches. How can I clean up the mesh around the branches? Are there better techniques for drawing branched curves *that also supports tampering and bevel effects*?

[image: bad mesh]

Comment: AFAIK there is no _faster_ technique. May I ask what the purpose of your mesh is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in *face selection mode* select the trunk with <kbd>L</kbd>, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type ***Intersect***. Unselect it, then select a branch and hide it (<kbd>H</kbd>). Delete all the faces inside the intersection edge, unhide the branch (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) then join verices to create a clean topology. Then remove the rest of the branch's vertices. Finally *remove doubles* (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*).
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: You still have one N-gon to split...

Comment: You're eagle-eyed man :). But yeah, you're right- it requires additional edge loop.